# Link a node to a png in Riak causing the json to not return

Tags: riak

I ran

```
 curl -v -X PUT http://localhost:10018/riak/animals/polly?returnbody=ture -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"nickname" : "Sweet Polly Purebred", "breed" : "Purebred"}'
```

When I fetch /riak/animals/polly I get the expected:

```
 - {
"nickname": "Sweet Polly Purebred",
"breed": "Purebred"
}
```

I have /riak/photos/polly.png.

I want to link polly to point to the photos. I tried:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:10018/riak/animals/polly -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Link </riak/photos/polly.png; riaktag=\"contains\""
```

and now when I fetch/riak/animals/polly, an empty page appears.

How do I link /riak/animals/polly to /riak/photos/polly.png?

Answer (score 1):

Your second command should have been:

`curl -X PUT http://localhost:10018/riak/animals/polly -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Link: </riak/photos/polly.png>; riaktag="contains"'`

Note the colon (`Link:`) and other angle bracket (`>`). In addition, I would suggest using single quotes when your strings don't need shell interpolation - that makes building the `Link:` header simpler.

Documentation: http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/theory/concepts/Links/

Comment: Hm, same issue with the command you posted. When I run:  curl -v -X PUT http://localhost:10018/riak/animals/polly?returnbody=ture -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"nickname" : "Sweet Polly Purebred", "breed" : "Purebred"}' I get a response from in terminal, not so on the PUT